# Replace first instance in Notepad++ using Regex

Tags: notepad++, regex

I'm completely new to RegEx and could really use some help with my dilemma. I have a large text file of IP addresses and corresponding hosts:

```
157.55.33.47 msnbot-157-55-33-47.search.msn.com
157.56.93.62 msnbot-157-56-93-62.search.msn.com
etc...
```

I need a find and replace algorithm that appends to the beginning and end of each line and replaces the delimiter, which in this case is just a space.

e.g. the output after running the regex should be:

```
'text1' 157.55.33.47 'text2' msnbot-157-55-33-47.search.msn.com 'text3'
'text1' 157.56.93.62 'text2' msnbot-157-56-93-62.search.msn.com 'text3'
```

Answer (score 1):

Find `^([A-Za-z0-9.-]+) ([A-Za-z0-9.-]+)$`

Replace `'Text 1' \1 'Text 2' \2 'Text 3'`

Each bracket pair creates a Group, which is then put in the replace function in order with the `\1`, `\2` sections.